# Group or ungroup e-mail messages in the Inbox in OutlookWeb Office 365

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-web-app

I wonder how I do to group or ungroup e-mail messages in Office 365 OutlookWeb Input Box? Showing + to expand all of the emails the group and - to remove the expansion.

Answer (score 1):

That stupid "conversations" option was driving me crazy but I finally figured out how to disable it:

Next to header "Inbox" there's dropdown "All." Click on that and at the bottom you'll see option "View as." Click on "messages."

Comment: Thank you I agree, this is a very stupid feature, since it impedes people to find previous emails by the old dates as they get hidden in the conversation. Missing also some hint in configuration...